# Java - decrement variable in while loop and print list

Tags: java, while-loop, decrement

teamsalary = 600000
avgSalindivindiv = 20000

How many team members can a team hire if their budget is 600000 and the average individual salary is 20000.

I want to print a list that looks like this:

```
0
1
2
3
...all the way to 30
```

Here is my code so far which does not work:

```
int teamsalary = 600000;
int avgSalindivindiv = 20000;
int numofpeople = 0;
while(teamsalary >= 0) {
    System.out.println(numofpeople);
    teamsalary = teamsalary - (numofpeople * avgSalindiv);
    numofpeople++;
    break;
}
```

Comment: You want just print 0....to ast number

Comment: Why are you using `break` there?  byt he way, you should describe *how* it does not work and post a small, complete, compilable example.

Comment: Please review the thoughtful answers given below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only glaring problem I see with your logic is the following line:

```
teamsalary = teamsalary - (numofpeople * avgSalindiv);
```

Here, you are subtracting the average salary multiplied by the running total number of people, which does not make sense.  Instead, you want to subtract the same average `avgSalindiv` during each iteration of your loop.  Try using this code instead:

```
int teamsalary = 600000;
int avgSalindivindiv = 20000;
int numofpeople = 0;
while (teamsalary >= 0) {
    System.out.println(numofpeople);
    teamsalary -= avgSalindiv;
    ++numofpeople;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `teamsalary = teamsalary - (numofpeople * avgSalindiv);` because this will subtract 0 the first time, 20000 the second time, 40000 the third time, etc etc. You simply want to subtract 20000 each time (for each person added). You also need to keep variable names consistent. (you used both `avgSalindivindiv` and `avgSalindiv`)

```
int teamsalary = 600000;
int avgSalindivindiv = 20000;
int numofpeople = 0;
System.out.println(numofpeople);

// subtracting avgSalindivindiv here prevents loop from running an extra time
while((teamsalary-=avgSalindivindiv) >= 0) {
    numofpeople++;
    System.out.println(numofpeople);
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `break` like this:

```
int teamsalary = 600000;
int avgSalindivindiv = 20000;
int numofpeople = 0;
while (teamsalary >= 0) {
    System.out.println(numofpeople);
    teamsalary = teamsalary - (numofpeople * avgSalindivindiv);
    numofpeople++;
}
```